# Yii creating empty assets folders

Tags: yii, wampserver

I'm running a Yii app with Wampserver, I pulled it from a git repository so it had no assets folders, I had to manually create each one because it was throwing a CException.

Now when I load any page Yii creates some folders with random names inside my assets folders, but they're all empty. **Edit:** Just noticed one of the folders created is full of files, but the other is totally empty and that's where it is trying to load all bootstrap files.

I've tried deleting them again but I have the same result, also tried adding SAFE_MODE in php.ini, running wamp as admin and adding this in the apache conf:

`<Directory "*/assets/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>`

I read the '[Understanding assets](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/)' post but the only useful thing I found was:

> It's important that the directory be writable by the webserver user so
>   that Yii can publish the resources there when needed

Yet I can't find how to do it for Wampserver

So, what am I supposed to do?

Thank You

Comment: exactly what exception are you getting ? it could be unrelated but cause assets folder problems

Comment: it is writable, so Yii created the empty directories ...
what version of Yii you are trying to use?

Comment: After creating the assets folder I don't get an exception, but the browser tries to load some .css and .js in one of those subdirectories which is empty.
Yii version: 1.1.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what was going on, the application is using a bootstrap component which has an "assets" folder as well, since git was ignoring that folder it was empty and the component wasn't able to publish the files in the application assets. I just put the original component files inside that folder and the problem is now solved.

Comment: Another way to force git to keep empty folders is to add an empty file called `.gitkeep` in that folder. (It can be any name).